# C#__ adding string into string using length

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, string-length

In my program, I'm trying to add a comma for a number that's length is more than 3. For example if number is 1000, it should output 1,000.
However I can't find out how to add on remaining numbers after I put comma into first one. The code below is what I've got:

```
// if the answer is more than 999
string answerThousand = Convert.ToString(lbl_NumResult.Text);

if (answerThousand.Length > 3) 
{
    lbl_NumResult.Text = answerThousand[1] + "," + answerThousand[ /* What must be here to add remaining numbers? */];
}
```

Comment: Why `answerThousand[1]`, not the `answerThousand[0]`? String has zero based index

Comment: That's where I thought to put the comma after first number.

Comment: You can use `string.Format` with `N`, or string interpolation, like `lbl_NumResult.Text = $"{answerThousand:N}";` or `N0`

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot that 0 is the starting value, not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass a formatter to the `ToString` method:

```
decimal inputValue = 0;
if (decimal.TryParse(lbl_NumResult.Text, out inputValue))
{
    string answerThousand = inputValue.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#NFormatString